# hashtable with dynamic values

Tags: c++, c++11, hashtable, unordered-map

I am trying to create a hashtable that is updated dynamically as a given algorithm runs. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> hashtable;
    hashtable.emplace(0,0);

    if(hashtable[0]==0) 
    {
        hashtable.emplace(0,1);
    }

    for (auto itr = hashtable.begin(); itr != hashtable.end(); itr++)
    {
         printf("%d : %d", (*itr).first, (*itr).second);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The strange part is that after trying to overwrite the value of `hashtable[0]` it stays the same. Is there any way to make a hashtable with ovewritable ie. mutable values?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to replace the value corresponding to key `0`, then use [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) to do it.

```
if(hashtable[0]==0) {
    hashtable[0] = 1;
}
```

[`unordered_map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) will only insert an entry if the key doesn't already exist in the map, which is not the case in your example.